# C++ is mixing my strings?

Tags: c++, string, memory, char, mixing

I have this really simple c++ function I wrote myself.
It should just strip the '-' characters out of my string.
Here's the code

```
char* FastaManager::stripAlignment(char *seq, int seqLength){
    char newSeq[seqLength];
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<seqLength; i++) {
        if (seq[i] != '-') {
            newSeq[j++]=seq[i];
        }
    }

    char *retSeq = (char*)malloc((--j)*sizeof(char));
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
        retSeq[i]=newSeq[i];
    }
    retSeq[j+1]='\0'; //WTF it keeps reading from memory without this
    return retSeq;
}
```

I think that comment speaks for itself.
I don't know why, but when I launch the program and print out the result, I get something like

`'stripped_sequence''original_sequence'`

However, if I try to debug the code to see if there's anything wrong, the flows goes just right, and ends up returning the correct stripped sequence.

I tried to print out the memory of the two variables, and here are the memory readings

memory for seq: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHI8k.png

memory for *seq: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqVkX.png

memory for retSeq: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9uvI.png

memory for *retSeq: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioFsu.png

(couldn't include links / pics because of spam filter, sorry)

This is the code I'm using to print out the strings

```
for (int i=0; i<atoi(argv[2]); i++) {
    char *seq;
    if (usingStructure) {
        seq = fm.generateSequenceWithStructure(structure);            
    }else{
        seq = fm.generateSequenceFromProfile();
    }
    cout<<">Sequence "<<i+1<<": "<<seq<<endl;
}
```

Now, I have really no idea about what's going on.

Comment: can you use std::string instead of char*?

Comment: Sure, I guess.. But I want to figure out what's going on here!

Comment: This is not valid standard C++. Standard C++ does not offer variable length arrays.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1 -- by definition

Comment: OK, you might have a compelling reason not to use std::string. But tell me, why are you using TWO output buffers in the function? Wouldn't one do? And why `malloc` instead of `new`? And why, even if we disregard the missing `\0`, do you allocate one char too few for the second output buffer? And why doesn't "the code I'm using to print out the strings" call the problematic function at all?

Comment: Please do yourself a favor, throw away that C++ book, you're currently reading and grab a better one. This is horrible and fragile code. You do know that you leak if you forget to free the dynamically allocated memory, right? Things could be *so* simple. Use and appreciate std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you put the terminating zero of a C string outside the allocated space. You should be allocating one extra character at the end of your string copy, and adding `'\0'` there. Or better yet, you should use `std::string`.

```
char *retSeq = (char*)malloc((j+1)*sizeof(char));
for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
    retSeq[i]=newSeq[i];
}
retSeq[j]='\0';
```

> it keeps reading from memory without this

This is by design: C strings are zero-terminated. `'\0'` signals to string routines in C that the end of the string has been reached. The same convention holds in C++ when you work with C strings.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight your example code can be shortened a bit by using strncpy.

Comment: @MrLister This is mostly OP's code, lines 10..14 from the post. All I did was correcting it slightly to avoid the off-by-one error: removed `--`, added `+1` in one place, and removed `+1` in the other. I understand that it could be optimized, but I wanted to stay as close as possible to the original.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use std::string, simply do this:

```
std::string FastaManager::stripAlignment(const std::string& str)
{
   std::string result(str);
   result.erase(std::remove(result.begin(), result.end(), '-'), result.end());
   return result;
}
```

This is called "[erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)".

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you would be best off using `std::string` unless you have really very good reason otherwise:

```
std::string FastaManager::stripAlignment(std::string value)
{
    value.erase(std::remove(value.begin(), value.end(), value.begin(), '-'), value.end());
    return value;
}
```

When you are using C strings you need to realize that they are null-terminated: C strings reach up to the first null character found. With code you posted you introduced an out of range assignment as you allocated 'j' elements and you assign to `retSeq[j + 1]` which is two character past the end of the string (surely you mean `retSeq[j] = 0;` anyway).